# duplicate entries are inserting automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, duplicates

Hello I am working with php `codeigniter`.My issue is that when i am inserting data ito the mysql table it works fine, but rarely it is added (same data) multiple times.I don't want this and didn't give any code for it
my insert code is below

```
$job = array(
    'emp_id'=>$this->input->post('employee'),
    'invoice'=>$this->input->post('job'),
    'amount'=>$this->input->post('amount'),
    'assigned_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
$this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('employee'));
$this->db->where('status',1);
$query = $this->db->get('employee');
if($query->num_rows()==0)
{
    if($this->db->insert('job',$job))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Success');
    }
    $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('employee'));
    $this->db->update('employee',array('status'=>1));
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code written here , first you are inserting the record and then updating it. May be you are doing something in the else statement which you haven't pasted here.

Comment: No..I am inserting job for an employee in job table and after that changing status of employee in employee for no longer he is available until he get complete the assigned work

Comment: can you please paste the whole function here so i will let you know if you there is flaw in flow.